# How much of a file has been read

Tags: c++, c++11, stream

I have a program which reads a 10 MByte file and processes the data as the data is being read in 4K chunks.  The test usually takes 1 min - 2 min. But there are some instances when the program takes more than 10 min, at which point the test it killed and a core is generated.  Following is the code that reads the file:

```
    string filename("data.out");
    ifstream ifs;
    vector<char> buf(4096);

    ifs.open(filename,  ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!ifs.is_open()) {
            cout << "ERROR : " << filename << "can't be opened." << endl;
            VERIFY(ifs.is_open());
    }

    while (!ifs.eof()) {
            ifs.read(buf.data(), buf.size());     <======== Line 1
            process_data (buf.data(), ifs.gcount());   <======== Line 2
    }
    ifs.close();
```

I have two cores that show the program is stuck at Line 1 and Line 2.

Top of bt of core1 at Line 1:

```
#0  0x00007f942a462175 in std::istream::read (this=0x7fff4ce69de0,
__s=0x9120000 "\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324\324"..., __n=4096) at /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc:651
```

Top of bt of core2 at Line 2:

```
#0  0x00000000004375f3 in std::__addressof<char> (__r=@0x7fa3176391a6: -128 '\200') at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/move.h:47
#1  0x0000000000436cd4 in std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::data (this=0x7fff346ad770)
at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:859
```

Initially, from core1,  I thought the issue was with ifs.read() taking a long time.  But after the second core, I am thinking the issue might be related to vector::data().

Is there a way I can tell if any part of the file has been read, by inspecting certain fields (e.g file offset) stored in ifstream.

I don't like posting dump of large structure, but here it is if someone can shed some light how I can figure out from this dump how much of the 10MB has been read.

```
(gdb) p ifs
$3 = warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' value
{
  <std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >> = {
    <std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >> = {
      <std::ios_base> = {
        _vptr.ios_base = 0xfbfcc0,
        static boolalpha = std::_S_boolalpha,
        static dec = std::_S_dec,
        static fixed = std::_S_fixed,
        static hex = std::_S_hex,
        static internal = std::_S_internal,
        static left = std::_S_left,
        static oct = std::_S_oct,
        static right = std::_S_right,
        static scientific = std::_S_scientific,
        static showbase = std::_S_showbase,
        static showpoint = std::_S_showpoint,
        static showpos = std::_S_showpos,
        static skipws = std::_S_skipws,
        static unitbuf = std::_S_unitbuf,
        static uppercase = std::_S_uppercase,
        static adjustfield = std::_S_adjustfield,
        static basefield = std::_S_basefield,
        static floatfield = std::_S_floatfield,
        static badbit = std::_S_badbit,
        static eofbit = std::_S_eofbit,
        static failbit = std::_S_failbit,
        static goodbit = std::_S_goodbit,
        static app = std::_S_app,
        static ate = std::_S_ate,
        static binary = std::_S_bin,
        static in = std::_S_in,
        static out = std::_S_out,
        static trunc = std::_S_trunc,
        static beg = std::_S_beg,
        static cur = std::_S_cur,
        static end = std::_S_end,
        _M_precision = 6,
        _M_width = 0,
        _M_flags = 4098,
        _M_exception = std::_S_goodbit,
        _M_streambuf_state = 5,
        _M_callbacks = 0x0,
        _M_word_zero = {
          _M_pword = 0x0,
          _M_iword = 0
        },
        _M_local_word = {{
            _M_pword = 0x0,
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0,
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0,
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0,
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0,
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0,
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0,
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0,
            _M_iword = 0
          }},
        _M_word_size = 8,
        _M_word = 0x7fff4ce69f20,
        _M_ios_locale = {
          static none = 0,
          static ctype = 1,
          static numeric = 2,
          static collate = 4,
          static time = 8,
          static monetary = 16,
          static messages = 32,
          static all = 63,
          _M_impl = 0x7f942a6e3aa0,
          static _S_classic = 0x7f942a6e3aa0,
          static _S_global = 0x7f942a6e3aa0,
          static _S_categories = 0x7f942a6c86a0,
          static _S_once = 2
        }
      },
      members of std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >:
      _M_tie = 0x0,
      _M_fill = 0 '\000',
      _M_fill_init = false,
      _M_streambuf = 0x7fff4ce69df0,
      _M_ctype = 0x7f942a6e3d20,
      _M_num_put = 0x7f942a6e4040,
      _M_num_get = 0x7f942a6e4030
    },
    members of std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >:
    _vptr.basic_istream = 0xfbfc98,
    _M_gcount = 0
  },
  members of std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >:
  _M_filebuf = warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >' value
{
    <std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >> = {
      _vptr.basic_streambuf = 0xfc0a70,
      _M_in_beg = 0x6306000 "\317\317\317\......320\320\320\320"...,
      _M_in_cur = 0x6307fff "",
      _M_in_end = 0x6307fff "",
      _M_out_beg = 0x0,
      _M_out_cur = 0x0,
      _M_out_end = 0x0,
      _M_buf_locale = {
        static none = 0,
        static ctype = 1,
        static numeric = 2,
        static collate = 4,
        static time = 8,
        static monetary = 16,
        static messages = 32,
        static all = 63,
        _M_impl = 0x7f942a6e3aa0,
        static _S_classic = 0x7f942a6e3aa0,
        static _S_global = 0x7f942a6e3aa0,
        static _S_categories = 0x7f942a6c86a0,
        static _S_once = 2
      }
    },
    members of std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >:
    _M_lock = {
      __data = {
        __lock = 0,
        __count = 0,
        __owner = 0,
        __nusers = 0,
        __kind = 0,
        __spins = 0,
        __list = {
          __prev = 0x0,
          __next = 0x0
        }
      },
      __size = '\000' <repeats 39 times>,
      __align = 0
    },
    _M_file = {
      _M_cfile = 0x70186c0,
      _M_cfile_created = true
    },
    _M_mode = 12,
    _M_state_beg = {
      __count = 0,
      __value = {
        __wch = 0,
        __wchb = "\000\000\000"
      }
    },
    _M_state_cur = {
      __count = 0,
      __value = {
        __wch = 0,
        __wchb = "\000\000\000"
      }
    },
    _M_state_last = {
      __count = 0,
      __value = {
        __wch = 0,
        __wchb = "\000\000\000"
      }
    },
    _M_buf = 0x6306000 "\317\317\317\317\317\......320\320\320\320\320"...,
    _M_buf_size = 8192,
    _M_buf_allocated = true,
    _M_reading = true,
    _M_writing = false,
    _M_pback = 0 '\000',
    _M_pback_cur_save = 0x0,
    _M_pback_end_save = 0x0,
    _M_pback_init = false,
    _M_codecvt = 0x7f942a6e3f60,
    _M_ext_buf = 0x0,
    _M_ext_buf_size = 0,
    _M_ext_next = 0x0,
    _M_ext_end = 0x0
  }
}
(gdb)
```

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: `vector::data()` just returns a pointer, it's instantaneous. You sure it's not just your `process_data()`? The code looks fine.

Comment: BTW dont use [`while(!eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Why are you using a `vector<char>` instead of a `char[]` ?

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris  No reason really, could have easily allocated a char buf[4096].

Comment: What does `process_data(data, 0)` ?

Comment: @Barry  That's my understanding of vector::data().  The cores that I have does not show the program counter in process_data() when the process was killed, but that could be a timing thing.  process_data() is not anything complicated, basically calculating md5sum.

Comment: @DieterLücking  I modified the code a bit, but process_data() is basically doing a call to MD5_Update().  I removed the md5 calls as I don't think that is causing the issue.  And this issue is pretty intermittent.

Comment: @AhmedA the question wasn't "what does `process_data` do, it was "What does `process_data(data, 0)` do?"  Fenceposts often screw up code.

Comment: @Yakk  Ok, sorry about that.  process_data(data, 0) is basically a noop.  I verified that.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Do you mind elaborating, why not use !eof().  Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedA Click on the link in my earlier comment.  It is a much better description than I can give here.

Comment: @AhmedA: Because you're testing for EOF _before_ your attempt to read? That's backwards. Instead test the result of the read...

Comment: @ahmedA  problem is probably in `process_data`.  Feeding it `0` is going to only happen when your file is a multiple of 4096 bytes under the above code, so it seems like the likely cause of your problem, but any kind of stack corruption leaking out of it could explain your bad behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do not loop on `eof`.

```
while (ifs.read(buf.data(), buf.size())) {
  size_t read = ifs.gcount();
  if(read==0) break; // don't trust passing `0` to `process_data`:
  process_data(buf.data(), read);
  if (read<buf.size()) break; // if we finished, end.
}
```

Finding the end of input is best done by attempting io, and noticing something went wrong.  In this case, we read, count how many bytes we read, and when we read 0 bytes or have read fewer bytes than we expected to read, we decide there isn't any more data to come.

We also end if any failbit has been set on `ifs` by the IO operation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why not to use !eof() as a condition to break out of the while loop?   I understand your code/log, using gcount(), but what cases (corner cases I presume) makes use of eof() a bad choice?  Is this a standard recommendation when using ifstream?

Comment: I would suggest using `while (ifs.read(buf.data(), buf.size())) { ...` instead of `while (true) { ...`

Comment: Please ignore my request for reasons not to use eof(), I missed the link posed by NathanOliver above.

Comment: How does this explain the problem?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit It doesn't explain much of anything.  It attempts to solve the problem.  Added some elaboration.

Comment: Okay I'll rephrase. How does this solve the problem?